# Debian - how to build in separate directory?

Tags: debian, packaging

I want to distribute a specialized GCC on debian.  Since GCC requires that it be built in a separate directory from the source directory, where neither is a subdirectory of the other (AFAIK), the standard debian/rules file won't work, as it puts build directory as a subdirectory of the source directory.  I took a look at debian's GCC rules file, and it's hugely overcomplicated for my needs.

So my question:  How do you get debhelper to use a source and build directory inside of the package directory?  By default, package_dir==src_dir.  How can I get this layout:

```
package/
   src/
      configure, ...
   build/
      libgcc/, ... 
   debian/
      control, ...
```

Answer (score 3):

this obviously heavily depends on your debian/rules.
a good start

```
#!/usr/bin/make -f
%:
     dh $@ --builddirectory=build
```

alternatively you could override the auto_build target completely (or partially) to fit your needs:

```
override_dh_auto_build:
     #build gcc as it is supposed to be built
```

and of course you could just check, how the gcc maintainers do it...